# Cutting down minmax game trees

Tags: python, minmax

so I'm trying to code an ai for a game called nim (misere version) and its one of my first attempts trying the use the minmax algorithm. If we ignore the game nim and use noughts and crosses to demonstrate the problem. I want to generate a game tree but it gets quite resource intensive when a game state occurs twice but has 2 ways to get to it. e.g:
~ = empty spot

X 0 X

0 ~ ~

~ ~ ~

Regardless of which ones were placed first it is the same players turn and the game state is the same, however generating these game states would duplicate the tree spanning from this. How would I link the two so it only generates it once?

Comment: You would produce an immutable, unique value for your state, like (in Python) a tuple. Then use that as key in a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.